# ArcGIS Flex API: Loop thru map graphics and make them visible

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex

Using the flex viewer 2.4 and Flex 4.5 SDK.
I have a bunch of map graphics stored in a map layer. Initially, each graphic is set to visible = false. At the click of a button, I want to loop over each graphic, set it to visible = true, wait three seconds, then onto the next graphic and do the same.

Problem:  the graphics don't become visible in the loop - they become visible all at once after the button click event handler has returned.

I've tried doing a refresh() on the graphics and the graphic layer in the loop, but that does not help.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that flash does not really have a different Thread for the UI. SO when you are running the code, the UI does not draw.

A work around would be to have a timer, and on the timer event, iterate to the next graphics and make it visible.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try.  Is there a way to send a token object to the timer, similar to what you can do with a HTTPService call?

Comment: Yup, I used the timer.  I had to extend the Timer class so I could pass a data object (the graphic to be made visible) to the listener function.  Thanks.